# ContactsAPI Wrapper library

Tags: java, android, class

I have found wrapper class for managing contacts, but I am constantly getting that application has stopped unexpectedly. I am trying to get some good and working code to start building open source library for managing contacts that would be simple enough for general use.

Code was found on www(dot).higherpass(dot)com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Idea is to make working example of using this, I just cannot succeed in this.

Here is the test project: 
http://filebin.ca/uzpgaq/HelloAndroid.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you get an application has stopped unexpectedly error, a stack trace of the Exception that was thrown should pe printed to log. Use logcat in Eclipse or for example the aLogcat app.
Then search for messages with your app's name. In Eclipse you can also create a filter to see only the messages of your app.

If you found the stack trace, see if it gives you a hint where the error could be.
If not, post it here and maybe we can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this wrapper class successfully in my project, both for SDK < 1.6 and SDK > 2.0 - from the same site and article.

All I can say is that it can work great - you just need to check your usage of it. Post a stack trace and it will be much easier to answer.